# How to make Azure App Service Web Apps serve my website out of my repoRoot/src/views/ folder as the website root?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

In one of my git repos, I've got a simple HTML website with the following folder structure:

```
repo root:
  --reference
    --developer-notes.txt
    --i-am-not-website-code.txt
    --i-am-not-meant-to-be-served-by-web-server.txt
    --etc.txt
  --src
    --views
      --index.html
      --etc.html
    --content
      --foo.css
      --etc.css
      --images
        --foo.png
        --etc.png
    --scripts
      --foo.js
      --etc.js
```

I just created a **App Service Web App** on Azure, configured it to pull the source out of my repo, and deployed it.

I made sure that the **Application Settings** -> **Default Document** list had an entry for the `index.html` file.

However, as understood, due to my folder structure, I can only view my website if I go to:

```
foo.azurewebsites.net/src/views/index.html
```

I cannot go just to:

```
foo.azurewebsites.net/
```

and see my `index.html` page.

Now, I can change my folder structure by putting my HTML pages in the root, to make the website appear at `foo.azurewebsites.net/`. But I was wondering if there was a way to not have to do that, esp. given that every repo also stores stuff *other* than the source code, for example in my case the **Reference** folder, and most repos have the source, which only one of the many artifacts, in the **source** folder.

Is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is to change the virtual path for your root application to point to your views folder in the `Virtual applications and directories` section of your `Application settings`. That way you will have `foo.azurewebsites.net/` serve your `index.html` file.

Another thing you will have to do in this case, is to set the virtual application paths for your `content` and `scripts` folders (and the reference folder if you need to access it's content from the web) since they are not under your `views` folder.

Given your folder structure, it would look something like this:

[image: Virtual applications]